# Autowired class from the jar file outside the classes

Tags: java, spring

How can the Class in a jar file get scanned by the `<context:component-scan base-package="" />`. I am getting the below error for my autowired class.

`SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.quartz.Scheduler com.path.controller.MyController.scheduler; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.quartz.Scheduler] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

code:

```
package com.path.controller;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;

@Controller
public class MyController{

   @Autowired
   Scheduler scheduler;
}
```

This scheduler is inside the jar file `quartz-oracle-2.1.6.jar` and is under `WEB-INF\lib`. This `lib` is outside the `classes` folder of the deployment package. In the `applicationcontext.xml` i have the below entry,

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.path" />`

Comment: Which version of spring are you using . Also did you tried using <context:annotation-config>

Comment: 3.2.4.RELEASE. I haven't tried <context:annotation-config>

Comment: Try add `<context:component-scan base-package="org.quartz" />` and check ?

Comment: No. That is not working. Same error.

Comment: Try `<context:component-scan base-package="classpath*:com.path" />`

Answer (score 2):

When you export the jar file using the export utility in eclipse there is a option called Add directory entries. Check this option and export the jar file, this will solve the problem

Comment: But I am not exporting any jar.

Comment: Just want to thank you, this solved a problem our team has had for years exporting jars from Eclipse that worked from other build tools. Did not realize a simple option in Eclipse had such an impact on Spring

Answer (score 1):

I'm  guessing you haven't defined your scheduler  bean. You need to first define the bean in order to inject into your controller.

In your `applicationcontext.xml` first define a bean with type `Scheduler`.
You might need something like  below.  Be sure to check  out  the  quartz  documentation to  check which scheduler  you need and how to instantiate  it.

```
<bean id="schedulerFactory" 
    class="org.quartz.StdSchedulerFactory" />

<bean id="scheduler" class="org.quartz.Scheduler"  factory-bean="schedulerFactory" factory-method="getDefaultScheduler" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As the exception complains "No qualifying bean of type [org.quartz.Scheduler]" , we will have to define the bean of type org.quartz.Scheduler, But that is not possible without any concrete implementation of the same, So , we will have to get a concrete implementation from the Factory class org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory and it's non static method getScheduler().

Hence, you will have to add following two lines in you context xml file and it will work , I have verified the same with the same version of spring which you are using :

```
<bean id="schedulerFactory"   class="org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory" />    

<bean id="scheduler" class="org.quartz.Scheduler"  factory-bean="schedulerFactory" factory-method="getScheduler" />
```

A console output after printing the initialized bean gives this :

```
  scheduler=org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler@536aaa8d
```